# How to reload/refresh a table when you populated the table via jsp scriptlet

Tags: jsp, html-table, jstl, reload, scriptlet

My tables are populated using jsp scriptlets.
Displaying is not a problem but when I do a submit which will do an add on the DB.
I want my table to reload the new result on the table, but I think because I'm using jsp scriptlet 
I may have to reload the whole page but I don't want to do that, is there a way I could
refresh/reload my table with the new result?

---

```
    <% 
    List<Person> list = Function.doQueryFromDB();
    for(Person person : list)
    { %>

        <TR>
            <TH ><%=person.getName()%><B></B></FONT>
        </TR>
    <%
    }
    %>
    </table>
```

---

```
    <% 
    List<Person> list = Function.doQueryFromDB();
    pageContext.setAttribute("person", list);
    %>

    <table id="sampTable">
    <c:forEach  var="per" items="${person}">
        <tr>
              <td><c:out value="${per.name}"  /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rearrange the business code so that the data is loaded from the DB *after* the new row is inserted.